# Converting Selection Sort into Generics <T>, T

Tags: c#, selection-sort

I am having a difficult time understanding how to convert Selection Sort into Generics. I have written a classic Selection Sort algorithm, could you please help me understand the insertion of `<T>` & `T`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 34, 17, 23, 35, 26, 9, 13 };

        //Print Array in Selection Sort
        SelectionSort(numbers);
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i] + " ");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void SelectionSort(int [] numArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length -1; ++i)
        {
            int minElement = numArray[i]; //Hold smallest remaining int @ i = 0
            int minLocation = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < numArray.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (numArray[j] < minElement)
                {
                    minElement = numArray[j]; // Update index of minElement
                    minLocation = j;
                }
            }

            //Swap
            if (minLocation != i)
            {
                int temp = numArray[minLocation];
                numArray[minLocation] = numArray[i];
                numArray[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can understand from my reading, I can only get as far as:

```
public static void SelectionSort<T>(T[] numArray) : IComparable
```

Thank you for any help that you can provide with the remainder of the Selection Sort algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, what you want to do is change the signature first. Since you no longer want to pass in an `int` array but a generic array, you need to change the parameter type to `T[]`. For that to work, you need to make the method generic by adding the type parameter there as well:

```
public static void SelectionSort<T>(T[] numArray)
```

Since the element type is now `T` instead of `int`, you need to replace all `int`s that referred to an element *value* by `T`. For example:

```
// minElement is an element of the array, so its type is T
T minElement = numArray[i];

// but the location is an index, so that stays an int
int minLocation = i;
```

Once you have done that, you will run into a compiler issue that you cannot use the `<` operator on `T`. This is because there is no information about the type `T` that says that it has an order. So what we do here is use a generic type constraint on `T`. We use the [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) interface here; using it changes the method signature into this:

```
public static void SelectionSort<T>(T[] numArray)
    where T: IComparable<T>
```

Once we have that, we can replace the `<` comparison with a call to `CompaterTo`:

```
if (numArray[j].CompareTo(minElement) < 0)
```

And that will be all there is to do for this method. This is the fully converted code:

```
public static void SelectionSort<T>(T[] numArray)
    where T: IComparable<T>
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length -1; ++i)
   {
       T minElement = numArray[i];
       int minLocation = i;

       for (int j = i + 1; j < numArray.Length; ++j)
       {
           if (numArray[j].CompareTo(minElement) < 0)
           {
               minElement = numArray[j];
               minLocation = j;
           }
       }

       if (minLocation != i)
       {
           T temp = numArray[minLocation];
           numArray[minLocation] = numArray[i];
           numArray[i] = temp;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't quite figure out where to place the CompareTo() and I was having a difficult time with the Swap - I wasn't putting the T temp. Thank you very much for the assistance!